# writing API's with JPA

Tags: spring, api, jakarta-ee, jpa, jdbc

In a big company, our team provides API's for accessing data on a oracle DB. Until now, we used plain SQL (JDBC) to get/write the data on the database.
So most of the existing API's looked like this (ok, not always that stupid :-)

```
public class DummyApi {

    private final DataSource datasource;

    public DummyApi(javax.sql.DataSource datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;

    }

    public void doSomething() throws SQLException {
         Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("plain sql query");
         statement.execute();
    }
}
```

Using such API's is simple, it doesn't matter if your end-application is plain java SE, spring or javaEE. Further, transaction-APIs works proper with this API's. We use them with spring TransactionManager (together with the TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy) and with JTA in CMA-Java EE applications.

Now we evaluate to use JPA in new API's. And the big question we currently struggle is the following: how can we provide a simple interface so that the end-application doesn't need to know about JPA? How can we initialize the EntityManager with a DataSource (for example provided as constructor parameter)? And how can we rollback if there are old, plain JDBC-APIs AND new JPA-APIs in the same transaction (begin/rollback in the end-application)?

Thanks for bringing a little light on the matter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JPA the datasource will normally be set in the persistence.xml.  If you need some sort of dynamic datasources, then you can pass the DataSource as a property to Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory().

Most JPA providers provide a way to get the JDBC Connection if you want to mix JDBC.  Normally this is accessed using em.unwrap(Connection.class).  You could also use JTA or Spring to have the transaction share the same connection.

Comment: Thx for your answer James. One question: can you help my how to pass the DataSource as property to the Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()- method? I suppose it's done by the map-parameter, but I can't find any useful example on google. Btw. we are working with hibernate